# How to alter a switch statement that essentially creates empty rounds?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, switch-statement

I am trying to make a four-person attack game that randomly selects the attacker and prints out the winner, but in my output, I keep getting empty rounds. I believe this is due to my switch statement but am unsure how to get the same result minus these essentially empty rounds. I have created an array of my characters to put into my randomly generated switch statement but with the if statements inside the cases are not skipped how I envisioned them being skipped. I've also tried removing the players from the array as they die, but that does not work and results in an error and exception message.

```
  import project3.characters.Plumber;
  import project3.characters.Vampire;
  import project3.characters.Werewolf;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Random;

  public class Game {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      GameCharacter player1 = new Plumber("Mario", 10, 20);
      GameCharacter player2 = new Fairy("Tinker Bell", 10, 20);
      GameCharacter player3 = new Vampire("Edward", 10, 20);
      GameCharacter player4 = new Werewolf("Derek", 10, 20);

      int round = 0;

      ArrayList<GameCharacter> player = new ArrayList<GameCharacter>. 
      ();

      player.add(player1);
      player.add(player2);
      player.add(player3);
      player.add(player4);

      while (player1.isAlive() || player2.isAlive() || 
          player3.isAlive() || player4.isAlive()) {
          System.out.println("Round " + (round + 1) + ": ");
          System.out.print(" " + player1 + " ");
          System.out.println(" " + player2);
          System.out.print(" " + player3 + " ");
          System.out.println(" " + player4 + " ");
          System.out.println();

          // Only two players can battle
          // if (round % 2 == 0) {
          // player1.hit(player2.attack());
          // } else
          // player2.hit(player1.attack())

          // All players randomly attack each other
          Random rand = new Random();
          int turn = rand.nextInt(12);
          switch (turn) {
          case 0:
              if (player1.isAlive() && player2.isAlive())
                  player1.hit(player2.attack());
              break;
          case 1:
              if (player1.isAlive() && player3.isAlive())
                  player1.hit(player3.attack());
              break;
          case 2:
              if (player1.isAlive() && player4.isAlive())
                  player1.hit(player4.attack());
              break;
          case 3:
              if (player1.isAlive() && player2.isAlive())
                  player2.hit(player1.attack());
              break;
          case 4:
              if (player3.isAlive() && player2.isAlive())
                  player2.hit(player3.attack());
              break;
          case 5:
              if (player4.isAlive() && player2.isAlive())
                  player2.hit(player4.attack());
              break;
          case 6:
              if (player1.isAlive() && player3.isAlive())
                  player3.hit(player1.attack());
              break;
          case 7:
              if (player3.isAlive() && player2.isAlive())
                  player3.hit(player2.attack());
              break;
          case 8:
              if (player3.isAlive() && player4.isAlive())
                  player3.hit(player4.attack());
              break;
          case 9:
              if (player1.isAlive() && player4.isAlive())
                  player4.hit(player1.attack());
              break;
          case 10:
              if (player4.isAlive() && player2.isAlive())
                  player4.hit(player2.attack());
              break;
          case 11:
              if (player3.isAlive() && player4.isAlive())
                  player4.hit(player3.attack());
              break;
          }

          if (!player1.isAlive()) {
              System.out.println(player1.getName() + " is dead!");
              // player.remove(0);
              // player1 = null
          }
          if (!player2.isAlive()) {
              System.out.println(player2.getName() + " is dead!");
              // player.remove(1);
              // player2 = null
          }
          if (!player3.isAlive()) {
              System.out.println(player3.getName() + " is dead!");
              // player.remove(2);
              // player3 = null
          }
          if (!player4.isAlive()) {
              System.out.println(player4.getName() + " is dead!");
              // player.remove(3);
              // player4 = null
          }

          if (!player4.isAlive() && !player2.isAlive() && 
              !player3.isAlive()) {
              System.out.println(player1.getName() + " is the 
           winner!");
              break;
          }
          if (!player4.isAlive() && !player1.isAlive() && 
             !player3.isAlive()) {
              System.out.println(player2.getName() + " is the 
           winner!");
              break;
          }
          if (!player4.isAlive() && !player2.isAlive() && 
          !player1.isAlive()) {
              System.out.println(player3.getName() + " is the 
         winner!");
              break;
          }
          if (!player1.isAlive() && !player2.isAlive() && 
          !player3.isAlive()) {
              System.out.println(player4.getName() + " is the 
        winner!");
              break;
          }
          
          
          round++;
          System.out.println();
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, great. If not, please explain in greater detail and clarity how your code is not working as expected, with example outputs. Also, note that we are unable to compile or run your code as yet, and you may consider creating and posting a [mre] code post. If you haven't gone through the [ask], now would be a great time to do so, to see other ways to improve your current and future questions. Also, the [help] and [tour] would be useful reads.

Comment: Also, if your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to maintain a flag if fight happens. Like this:

```
    boolean didFightHappen = true;
    while (any player alive) {
        //anounce round only if didFightHappen = true;
        // round 1 etc
        
        Random rand = new Random();
        int turn = rand.nextInt(12);
        didFightHappen = false;  // make flag false
        switch (turn) {
        case 0:
            //if fight happens then set
            // didFightHappen = true;
            break;
        }
        // at end of the switch
        if(didFightHappen == false) {
            continue; // this continues the while loop to next iteration without executing rest of the loop code
        }
        
    }
```

Here is the tiny version of your game :p

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
l.add(1); l.add(2); l.add(3); l.add(4);
        
Collections.shuffle(l);
while(l.size()>1) {
    int a = l.remove(0); 
    int b = l.get(0);
    System.out.println("Player " + b + " attacked player " + a );
    System.out.println(a + " died!");
}
System.out.println("Player " + l.get(0) + " is the winner!");
```

Output:

```
Player 3 attacked player 4
4 died!
Player 1 attacked player 3
3 died!
Player 2 attacked player 1
1 died!
Playe 2 is the winner!
```